# Client Secret Requirment For OAuth with PKCE extension

Tags: oauth-2.0

We're presently implementing an OAuth 2.0 server using the authorization code flow with the PKCE extension. In our current setup, we mandate the `client_secret` for the token endpoint when using the `authorization_code` grant type. Additionally, we do not employ any other Basic HTTP Authentication beyond the client_secret.

We serve two client types, both of which utilize our OAuth server:

1. **Public client** – These include single-page apps like websites and mobile apps without their own servers. They lack a secure method to store the client secret.
2. **Confidential client** – These clients operate their servers to process token exchanges and securely store their client secrets.

A teammate suggested removing the `client_secret` requirement when PKCE is utilized. However, I believe maintaining it as a requirement could offer consistency, reducing the need for extensive documentation and code handling. Furthermore, the client secret enhances security for the confidential client. Yet, for public clients unable to securely store it, the inclusion or exclusion of the client_secret might not significantly impact security.

We've encountered various perspectives on whether the `client_secret` requirement should be included for the token endpoint when PKCE is in use. The viewpoints vary considerably:

1. These days, we also tend to use PKCE in confidential server-side apps to prevent authorization code leakages, even though it was originally designed for public apps like mobile or desktop apps. In this case, you should definitely combine it with client authentication (i.e client secret validation). [Should Authorization flow use both secret and PKCE for a Web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793968/should-authorization-flow-use-both-secret-and-pkce-for-a-web-app)
2. "A Single Page Application (SPA) running in the browser would need to have the plaintext credentials in the end-users browser, and a mobile app would need to store it on the end-users phone. These are known as public clients, and this is when you would use PKCE without a client secret" https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/client-authentication-vs-pkce
3. OAuth.net said that PKCE isn't a form of client authentication or a replacement for a client secret or other forms of client authentication. https://oauth.net/2/pkce/

Taking an example, the Spotify API doesn't mandate a `client_secret` on its token endpoint when PKCE is used.
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow

Another example is Google, Google requires `client_secret` with PKCE.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#:%7E:text=Google%20supports%20the%20Proof%20Key%20for%20Code%20Exchange%20(PKCE)%20protocol%20to%20make%20the%20installed%20app%20flow%20more%20secure

The questions are:

1. **Does setting the `client_secret` as a requirement for the Token
   endpoint for authorization code with/without PKCE disrupt any
   conventions?**
2. **Is it necessary to include authentication for PKCE flow if the
   client_secret requirement is removed for public clients? Could we rely on the registered `redirect_uris` on our server and PKCE without authentication?**

In my view, there isn't a strict convention. And, Requiring the `client_secret` for public clients is not inherently harmful or problematic, even if they can't securely store it and not useful, but it is more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

PKCE solves a different security issue `client_secret` brings. You *should* always require it.

Even though the secret does nothing, it's not a good idea to include it. You're effectively teaching your users to store secrets in an insecure place, which might just cause confusion.

There's a really excellent draft (future RFC) that does into *everything* your ask and more and it states:

> it is NOT RECOMMENDED for authorization servers to require client authentication of browser-based applications using a shared secret

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps

This is coming from the experts.

Comment: Got it. So for a public client, we should not teach them to store client_secret on the public app. How about a confidential client, should it include client_secret? So in that case, should we separate two handling for confidential and public clients? 

Also, do we still need any authentication if PKCE is used for public clients? Thank you

Comment: I found the answer in 6.3.2.3. Client Authentication of the doc and 6.3.2.2. Registration of Browser-Based Apps, and it mainly for public clients. how about confidential client?